# How to set the GenericDirCtrl to show custom folder as top directory in wxpython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to show my folder as top directory in wxPython's GenericDirCtrl component. I tried SetPath() and path in my code but it only focuses the selected folder , not making it the top of the tree.

In my form's constructor i create it like that:

```
self.folder_tree_project = wx.GenericDirCtrl(self.pnl_edit, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, -1), wx.DIRCTRL_3D_INTERNAL | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, wx.EmptyString, 0)

self.folder_tree_project.ShowHidden(False)
bSizer5.Add(self.folder_tree_project, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
```

and then i am trying to change the top directory by using the working directory in my config file:

```
if self.config.workdir != "":
    # self.folder_tree_project.SetPath(self.config.workdir)
    # self.folder_tree_project.Path=self.config.workdir
```

both only focuses. Not changing the top directory.

Is there any way or attribute  to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [wx.GenericDirList](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/GenericDirCtrl.html#GenericDirCtrl.GetTreeCtrl) GetTreeCtrl() function to get the pointer to  its wx.TreeCtrl attribute, and then use the [TreeCtrl.AppendItem()](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TreeCtrl.html#TreeCtrl.AppendItem) to append the name of the directory you wanted to its root item.

its only the name of the directory however, and You're going to have to code its functionality, by binding mouse clicks and appending the directory's child files and child directories using os.walk (or by any other means), while working with the wx.TreeCtrl pointer.

maybe there's a better, embeded in wxpython api, way to do this, but i could'nt find anything in the documentation.

anyways here's the code for Adding the directory name to the wx.TreeCtrl pointer:

```
    DirectoryNameHere = "mypath"
    Bsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.folder_tree_project = wx.GenericDirCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, -1), wx.DIRCTRL_3D_INTERNAL | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, wx.EmptyString, 0)

    self.folder_tree_project.ShowHidden(False)
    Tree = self.folder_tree_project.GetTreeCtrl()
    Tree.AppendItem(Tree.GetRootItem(), DirectoryNameHere)

    Bsizer.Add(self.folder_tree_project,1,wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(Bsizer)
```

Comment: I think the same way with you but maybe there is a plugin or custom widget for this. Otherwise i have to write it  :) . And there is something which makes it more complicated than this. The working folder is not static and could be changed by user in runtime. Anyway thanks for your effort.