# GenericDirCtrl always shows the entire PC starting from C:\, How to set a custom directory as my root?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, wxpython

I am new to wxpython so please forgive me if my question is repeated. Also I saw few similar questions and tried the solutions but all resulted in the same result - which is my question now. My environment is python 3.6 and windows 10. Here's my code

```
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
DirectoryNameHere = "F:\\MyCaseWorkSpace"
self.folder_tree_project = wx.GenericDirCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,    wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, 450), wx.DIRCTRL_3D_INTERNAL | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, wx.EmptyString, 0)
self.folder_tree_project.ShowHidden(False)
Tree = self.folder_tree_project.GetTreeCtrl()
Tree.AppendItem(Tree.GetRootItem(), DirectoryNameHere)
sizer.Add(self.folder_tree_project,1,wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
```

But the result is something like below:

```
Windows(C:)
Recovery(D:)
DVD RW Drive(E:)
New Volume(F:)
F:\MyCaseWorkSpace
```

I have tried path with file:///, path with extra /, Unix Style Path, Windows Style Path but every time the result as above.

My Requirement is to take a directory path as input and display all the files and folders inside it (with filters) as a Tree.

Please help.

Comment: You might find this helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865659/how-to-set-the-genericdirctrl-to-show-custom-folder-as-top-directory-in-wxpython

Comment: Thanks Mike for the quick response. I have gone through that post and the solution does not work. It just lists those unwanted drives:(

Comment: I also found this thread that indicated there was a way to subclass `GenericDirCtrl`, but no examples were provided - http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Can-you-set-the-quot-root-quot-directory-for-wx-GenericDirCtrl-td2311294.html

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* quite an answer to your question. It disappoints in that wxPython does not necessarily move the selected folder into view, depending on the size of the frame. Still, it might get you closer.

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'test', size=(500,700))

        dir3 = wx.GenericDirCtrl(self, -1, 
                        dir='C:/Television',
                                 style=wx.DIRCTRL_SHOW_FILTERS |
                                       wx.DIRCTRL_3D_INTERNAL |
                                       wx.DIRCTRL_MULTIPLE,
                                 filter="Python files (*.py)|*.py")

app = wx.App()

frm = TestFrame(None)
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This is the appearance of this mock app.

[image: app]

Almost forgot: use the `dir` parameter.